# Get count of one-to-many records efficiently

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two tables: `App` (with a `release_id` field) and `User`.

### Models

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

### Class

```
class Stats::AppOverview
  def initialize(from:, apps:)
    @from = from || Date.new(2010)
    @apps = apps
  end

  def total_count
    { apps: { total: total_app, with_user: app_with_user } }
  end

  private

  def app_since
    @apps.where('created_at >= ?', @from)
  end

  def total_app
    devices_since.count
  end

  def app_with_user
    User.where(app: app_since).count
  end
end
```

I would like to return

1. the number of `app` records for a given array of `release_id`
2. the number of `app` records that belong to each user, satisfying other criteria

This is how I use the class

```
Stats::AppOverview.new(from: 1.month.ago.iso8601, 
  apps: App.where(release_id: [1,2,3,4,5,19,235]).total_count
#=> { apps: { total: 65, with_user: 42 } }
```

For the moment I do it in two queries, but is it possible to put them in the same query? Is this possible using active record?

Comment: Trying to get clarity here. What does "number `user` related" mean? Also, where does `devices_since` come from?

Comment: @BryanH User that have an `app_id` that is included in the first where clause.

Comment: So you are looking for the number of apps that belong to a given user AND have specific `release_id`s, right?

Comment: @BryanH Yes exactly

Comment: Okay, I clarified your question. See if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @BryanH that's far better

Comment: The results of each query are so different that it might be a fools errand. For  1 you want a collection of users - for number 2 a collection of apps. If you can think of result set that makes sense here maybe add it as a simple table diagram or JSON.

Comment: @max Thanks max. I need only count. I've added method response expected.